# How can I identify this chip, Motorola 00S72-C?

Tags: identification, components

Well, I guess it's identified as an 00S72-C, but I need the data sheet, or what this does.

I am working on a Ford EEC-IV system. I have 2 circuit boards, identical, but there is one chip that is present on the 6-cyl board but not on the 8-cyl board. Both computers have the exact same input and output pins.

Google does not show results for me. Motorola also does not have any close matches that I can find.

I do not have an oscilloscope, only DVM.

How can I know what this chip's function is?

The chip's location on the board is in the lower right-hand corner.

[image: Motorola 14 pin 00S72-C KAG9442]

[image: V6 EEC-IV board]

[image: V8 EEC-IV board]

Comment: With a DVM you can trace out the circuit around the chip. Can you show us a photo of the entire board?

Comment: It’s a fair chance it is a custom chip for Ford. The schematics for the ECU are available online but they don’t tell you much about the chip apart from some pin labels.

Comment: I will work on tracing out where it connects to.

Comment: Yes, custom chip for Ford. I know what all the other chips do, well at least 80% of them. I have the documents for those.

Comment: If it's a custom chip, you're out of luck if you need to replace it or anything. Why do you need to know what it is?

Comment: This semi-fishy site claims to have a datasheet for it if you register https://www.jotrin.com/product/parts/00S72_C. Could just be a scam of course. Though the "spot market" is where you will end up if you need very old obsolete/custom parts like this.

Comment: @Hearth, I am making use of every option available on the board, that may not have been an option with the vehicle. As an example, there is Ford's Tripminder, which shows mpg or litre/100km. The Tripminder is not an option for my truck, but the PCM/EEC-IV has the software enabled, as well as hardware enabled. Wanting to know what this extra chip is, so I can take advantage of what it does.

Comment: @Lundin, i've signed into that site before, not worth the effort, data sheet pdf links to motorola.com website, useless, but thank you for searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This chip receives its signal from the Knock Sensor, pin#23 on the EEC-IV.

This chips function is to convert the signal from the knock sensor, to a compatible signal that can be input into the CPU.

Specifically, for High Speed Input(HSI), the CPU requires:

- Vdd 4.5min, 5.0nom, 5.5max
- VL, voltage low, -0.3min, +1.26typ, +0.8max
- VH, voltage high, +2.0min, +1.60typ, Vdd+0.5

An assumption can be made that the sensor outputs 12v, and the CPU requires 5v.